# How to activate feature using powershell script?

Tags: powershell, site-collection, feature-activation, web-application

I need to activate specific feature to all site collection which is inside the  particular web application using powershell script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Get-SPWebApplication xxx | Get-SPSite -Limit ALL | % {Enable-SPFeature "xxx" -Url $_.Url}`

Comment: Get-SPWebApplication "Web App URL"| Get-SPSite -Limit ALL | % {Enable-SPFeature "Feature GUID" -Url $_.Url} Is my parameter correct?.I am missing anything?

Comment: Seems right. Usually I'd use Feature foldername but Guid is OK

Comment: small tip: use a GUID instead 'name' - it's more precise and less prone to error if there are similar feature names..

Comment: Name is a lot easier to read and as it ALWAYS are something like Company.Product.Solution[.SubFeature] there will never be a collision. GUID may be a bit faster, but activating/deactivating features using PowerShell is not where you get performance problems

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

`$site = Get-SPSite http://yourserver`

`$site | Get-SPWeb -limit all | ForEach-Object {Enable-SPFeature -Identity "FeatureName" -Url $_.Url}`

`$site.Dispose()`

Answer (score 0):

Per is spot on with the command, however I was receiving an error "The Feature is not a Farm Level Feature..."

Found the answer at http://rajeshch999.blogspot.com/2012/07/powerdhell-feature-is-not-farm-level.html. The feature name was different than the name of the wsp that I installed, looking up the name in the 14 hive made it work for me.

Also, I put it into a short script for ready access if I needed it again.

```
# Enable-SPFeatureOnWebApplication.ps1
# script to turn on a feature on all site collections on a web app
# look-up feature name in 14 hive if not working 

$waURL = "https://your.url"
$featureName = "your.feature.name"

Get-SPWebApplication $waURL | Get-SPSite -Limit ALL | % {Enable-SPFeature $featureName -Url $_.Url}
```

Answer (score -1):

other method:
http://www.stefanopaterno.com/post/2011/11/15/Pillole-di-SharePoint-Management-Shell.aspx

Comment: -1 for linking your own (non-English) blog article that contains only one stsadm command that doesn't answer this question (PowerShell command is needed)

Comment: Thanks for the -1 is right, I was racing and I was hoping it would be useful.